# is kmeans_lables or kmeans.predict to assign label for each sample in dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, k-means

I would like to add  cluster number to each sample in dataframe after applying kmeans custering on the dataframe. First, I wonder if both kmeans.lables_ and kmeans.predict() return same results?. I tried them both , but I see mismatch. I wonder which one to use?

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
kmeans5 = KMeans(n_clusters=5, max_iter=20, verbose=1) 
kmeans5.fit(wdf)
clusters5 = kmeans5.predict(wdf)
```

In same way, I initialize kmeans3 and kmeans2, and get clusters3 and clusters2 then I tried this

```
wdf2=wdf.copy()
wdf2['c5']=clusters5
wdf2['l5']=kmeans5.labels_
wdf2['c3']=clusters3
wdf2['l3']=kmeans3.labels_
wdf2['c2']=clusters2
wdf2['l2']=kmeans2.labels_
```

I got the following after wdf2[['c5','l5','c3','l3','c2','l2']].head(7), and you can see c5 and l5 are not matching !.

```
id      c5  l5  c3  l3  c2  l2
40419   0   2   2   2   1   1
41060   3   0   2   2   1   1
43284   3   3   2   2   1   1
45664   3   1   0   0   1   1
52014   3   0   2   2   1   1
53488   3   1   0   0   1   1
53895   0   2   2   2   1   1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They should be consistent on the training dataset.

From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html):

*"Also, the estimator will reassign labels_ after the last iteration to make labels_ consistent with predict on the training set."*

Comment: It is clustering, so I am using the fall dataset. I do not know why I get different results, do you think the order is different?

Comment: If you post the code you are using then we can help you better.

Comment: I added the code and edited the post

Comment: `labels_` and the result of `fit_predict` is consistent, you can check this by running first `fit_predict` and then immediately checking for the `labels_`. Note that label assigned to the same centroid can change across different run of `fit_predict`, but it just the cluster naming that changes